flutter_google_places freezes screen (Flutter)
I have the following floating button working with flutter_google_places:
FloatingActionButton.small(
            heroTag: 'places2',
            onPressed: () async {
              final sessionToken = Uuid().v4();

              Prediction? prediction = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                context: context,
                apiKey: 'APIKEY',
                mode: Mode.overlay,
                language: "es", // Configuración de idioma español
                components: [Component(Component.country, "es")],
                types: ["(cities)"],
                hint: "Buscar ciudad",
                startText: '',
                offset: 0,
                radius: 100000,
                strictbounds: false,
                region: "es",
                sessionToken: sessionToken,
              );

              if (prediction != null) {
                print('Prediction placeId: ${prediction.placeId}');
                print('Prediction description: ${prediction.description}');
              }
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.search_off),
          ),

Which works perfectly, flutter_google_places opens when I press it, and if I search for "Barcelona" it is searched correctly. The problem is that when you press "Barcelona" and close flutter_google_places, the map freezes.
If I open and close flutter_google_places (without entering the city), exactly the same thing happens. I tried putting flutter_google_places in an Appbar within the map and it happens exactly the same, it searches for the city but freezes the map.
I searched the internet without finding my mistake.

Could you clarify what you mean by closing the flutter_google_places? Additionally, could you provide a video demo of your app's behaviour so we can better understand your issue? Lastly, have you tried to check your console to see if  there's any error message?
